# Change Image Date of Google Street View API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

I am trying to find a way to load the Google Maps Street View for a specific time period by accessing the image date. On google maps it lets you go back as far as 2007. How can I make google load the map from another year instead of the current year?

Here's what I have but it's only loading the current map.

#### HTML

```
<body>
   <div id="streetview2011" class="street-view"></div>

   <script src="../js/lib/street-view.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDP87Ddl6sW6C-CXeoHlRxszGBfo1mlMT8&callback=initPano" async defer></script>
</body>
```

#### Javascript

```
function initPano() {

  var panorama2011 = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('streetview2011'), {
        position: {lat: 39.963325, lng: -75.202340},
        imageDate: '2011-07',
        addressControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        },
        imageDateControl: true,
        linksControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        enableCloseButton: false
  });

}
```

Comment: Getting a view from a particular date using the Street View API is not available as of the moment as far as the documentation is concerned. See [Street View API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro#introduction).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, accessing the Google Maps Street View panorama of a place for a specific time period is not yet available from the Google Maps Platform.

But, we do have an existing feature request for this in our Google Issue Tracker. To express your interest and to subscribe you to its latest updates, I suggest that you star this entry: https://issuetracker.google.com/35826204